# CI/CD for NextJs applications fails in Github Actions

Tags: node.js, next.js, babeljs, github-actions, cicd

this is my first question here :D

I'm setting up the CI/CD process for a NextJS application and everything is working fine locally but when I try to run the workflow in Github Actions the command `npm run build` fails. It says that it can't find the `babel-plugin-styled-components` package, but the package is there.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 15002",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "dyte-client": "^0.34.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "next": "^11.1.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-fade-in": "^2.0.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.2",
    "react-leaflet-enhanced-marker": "^1.0.21",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-simple-maps": "^2.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
    "reactn": "^2.2.7",
    "sass": "^1.44.0",
    "sharp": "^0.29.3",
    "sitemap": "^7.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "timezones-list": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "dependenciesLocal": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "dyte-client": "^0.34.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "next": "^11.1.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react-fade-in": "^2.0.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.2",
    "react-leaflet-enhanced-marker": "^1.0.21",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
    "reactn": "^2.2.7",
    "sass": "^1.44.0",
    "sitemap": "^7.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.23.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "delegates": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.57.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

deploy.yml

```
name: Staging deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "staging"

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

env:
  SOME_ENV_VARS: SOME_VALUE

jobs:
  build:
    name: CI Pipeline
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: staging
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: ["14.x"]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the files
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      # Install project dependencies, test and build
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
      - name: Run build
        run: npm run build
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
          CI: false

  deploy:
    name: CD Pipeline
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: staging
    needs: [build]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: ["14.x"]
        appname: ["main_app"]
        deploy-group: ["main_app_staging"]
        s3-bucket: ["main-app-codedeploy-staging"]
        s3-filename: ["main-app-codedeploy-staging-${{ github.sha }}"]
    steps:
      - name: Setup repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
      - name: Run build
        run: npm run build
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN }}
          CI: false

      # Configure AWS credentials

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEPLOY_ROLE }}
          role-session-name: OIDCSession
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

      # Deploy push to AWS S3
      - name: AWS Deploy push
        run: |
          aws deploy push \
          --application-name ${{ matrix.appname }} \
          --description "This is a revision for the ${{ matrix.appname }}-${{ github.sha }}" \
          --ignore-hidden-files \
          --s3-location s3://${{ matrix.s3-bucket }}/${{ matrix.s3-filename }}.zip \
          --source .

      # Create deployment to CodeDeploy
      - name: AWS Create Deployment
        run: |
          aws deploy create-deployment \
           --application-name ${{ matrix.appname }} \
           --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime \
           --deployment-group-name ${{ matrix.deploy-group }} \
           --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE \
           --s3-location bucket=${{ matrix.s3-bucket }},key=${{ matrix.s3-filename }}.zip,bundleType=zip \
```

The error

```
./node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-styled-components'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/work/adplist/adplist/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
- /home/runner/work/adplist/adplist/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/code-frame.js
- /home/runner/work/adplist/adplist/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-config.js
- /home/runner/work/adplist/adplist/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js
- /home/runner/work/adplist/adplist/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js
- /home/runner/work/adplist/adplist/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
- If you want to resolve "styled-components", use "module:styled-components"
    at loadPlugin.next (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
```

**EDIT 1:** Here is the babel file.

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "styled-components",
      { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
    ]
  ],
  "compact": false
}
```

Hope you can help me! :)

Comment: check your node ver and npm ver

Comment: I already did that and both environments are using the same versions, I also have that application deployed on Heroku with the same specs and there is working well. I cannot find a solution :(

Comment: can i see DockerFile ?

Comment: I'm not using Docker, but maybe that could solve the problem

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. Did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

I would try and add it to your `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies.` I have found that doing that will sometimes solve the issue of missing packages during ci/cd builds.